# Use VSSetConstantBuffers or VSSetConstantBuffers1?

Tags: rendering, directx11

I am wondering what is the performance difference between 2 constant buffer strategies.
For example, in my scene, there is a lot of objects. Some of them are static and others are not.

Strategy 1:
Create a big constant buffer containing all variables I need(objectToWorldMatrix etc). And use VSSetConstantBuffers1 with offsets to bind buffers.

Strategy 2:
Each object has its own constant buffer. Use VSSetConstantBuffers to bind buffers.

I feel Strategy 2 is better because I can cache static objects' constant buffers, which are unchanged between frames. Strategy 1 has to update the buffer in each frame. Am I right?

I am a newbie of DirectX. Any suggestion for these two strategies?

Comment: Most questions of the form "which is better for performance, A or B" can be answered more conclusively by profiling. It is entirely possible that A performs better in one game, while B performs better in another, based on all kinds of details of the types of rendering loads each game uses, their particular pipelines, etc. So your best bet is to profile your favorite one and stress-test it (add extra content to your scene — it doesn't have to be real final content), then measure whether the performance is adequate. If not, try the other, or try to isolate the bottleneck and ask how to fix that.

Comment: Strategy 3: a single small cbuffer that is updated for each object, is also viable. Pro: a single cbuffer bind per frame, con: multiple updates per frame. Depends on the cost of binding vs the cost of updating, but it might be the best option if updating cost is sufficiently low.